# Django Static folder access issue

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I want to access the images in the static folder
the image name is coming dynamically.

I am using this syntax:

```
"{% static 'theme/one page base/bgimages/"+num+".jpg' %}"
```

where num is a random number calculated at runtime using javascript.
but it is not working

Comment: define "it is not working".

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/theme/one%20page%20base/bgimages/%22%2Bnum%2B%22.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)  this error is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this this syntax,it will work:

```
"{% static 'theme/one page base/bgimages/' %}/"+num+".jpg"
```